# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - Fill new Array with looped Data from other Array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have a Scanner which sets the arrayLenght, then the array is filled with random numbers between 0 and 1000.

Next, I want to get all even numbers and store them in a new array. For that, I created a loop to count the size of the new array.

Second, I run the loop again and want to fill the new array with all even numbers from the original array.

If I test with a length of 1 or 2, the code sometimes works and the new array can be generated. If I work with an array lenght of like 10, I get an Error like:

`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 out of bounds for length 4`

For this Error example I have set up an array with a length of 10. I got 4 Even Numbers in it. The Count worked and changed to "4". Yet I get an Error.

```
    //GET A COUNT FOR THE LENGHT OF ARRAY
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayLenght; i++){
        if (dasArray[i] % 2 == 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println("COUNT " + count);
    
    
    //CREATE NEW ARRAY WITH ALL EVEN NUMBERS AND THE LENGHT OF COUNT
    int []dasGeradeArray = new int[count];
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayLenght; i++){
        if (dasArray[i] % 2 == 0) {
            dasGeradeArray[i]= dasArray[i];
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you think happens when `i >= count` in your second loop? You need to keep another counter besides `i` (let's call it `j`) and increment that only when needed, like `dasGeradeArray[j++]= dasArray[i];`

Comment: In your second for loop, you need to loop while `i < count`, obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the dasGeradeArray has half of the indexes that dasArray has. You shouldn't use the same i variable. You can add another variable that you increment each time you add something to dasGeradeArray:

/

```
/CREATE NEW ARRAY WITH ALL EVEN NUMBERS AND THE LENGHT OF COUNT
    int []dasGeradeArray = new int[count];
    int dasGeradeCounter = 0
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayLenght; i++){
        if (dasArray[i] % 2 == 0) {
            dasGeradeArray[dasGeradeCounter]= dasArray[i];
            dasGeradeCounter++;
        }
```